# how to search for column names in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have the following data frame `df2` and a vector `n`. How can I create a new data frame where df2 column names are same as vector `n`

```
df2 <- data.frame(x1=c(1,6,3),x2=c(4,3,1),x3=c(5,4,6),x4=c(7,6,7))
n<-c("x1","x4")
```

Comment: df2[, n] ? Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of these would work:

```
df2[n]

df2[, n] # see note below for caveat

subset(df2, select = n)
```

Note that in the second one if `n` can be of length one,  i.e. one column, then it returns a vector rather than a data frame and if you want it to always return a data frame you would need instead:

```
df2[, n, drop = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df3 <- subset(df2, select=c("x1", "x4"))
df3
```

hope it helps